# start a new activity by closing all the stacked activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

My activity stack:

```
Main -> Restaurant Menu -> Order Details.
```

When order is placed I need to close the **Restaurant Menu and Order Details** 
and Start new activity called Active Order

```
Main -> Active Order.  (need to close top 2 activity)
```

I have tried with all the options like below

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

All the solution I found behaving like below

1. Main -> Restaurant Menu -> Active Order. (close Order details)
2. only Active Order. (close everything and start new)

How can I achieve this.
Main -> Active Order. ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My idea that you could use is to set a SharedFile each time a new intent starts, and after you use `startActivity();`, I would put `finish();` after to close the current activity before it opens the new one.

Comment: no need found a solution with starting two activities. Not sure that is correct way to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used bellow like..

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can launch an activity like that:

```
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

This is a minimal example how you can create an Intent and start an Activity in Android.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Home.class); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActiveOrder.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

According to [Android Developers resource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) on Intent:

- `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` : If set in an `Intent` passed to `Context.startActivity()`, this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started.
- `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` : If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack.

After calling `startActivity(intent)` put this line for better accuracy:

```
YourActivity.this.finish();
```